# Regex image size - wrong output

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace an image size from an input URL.

Regex:

```
imgurl = imgurl.replace(/-[^.-]+(?=\.jpg)/, "-200x200");
```

Input image URL:

```
http://www.site-address.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/della-and-perry-300x300.jpg
```

Expected Output:

```
http://www.site-address.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/della-and-perry-200x200.jpg
```

Actual Output:

```
http://www.site-address.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/della-and-200x200.jpg
```

Not sure what I did here to get it to replace those letters as well. Regex isn't my strength, I'm still learning.

I would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: That regex works fine in my browser and only matches the -300x300.jpg

Comment: It seems to work for all images except for the one that I used in the example. Maybe it's just that image that is the outlier, and somehow causing an issue. Seems all others are fine.

Comment: It works with that exact same string.

Comment: `centurion-an-interview-with-director-neil-marshal-300x225.jpg` turns into `centurion-an-interview-with-director-neil-200x200.jpg`

Comment: Yeah, there's no way that regex is matching the -marshal- part. I think you are somehow running the replace twice, which would do that. Maybe you should post the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me your solution worked as well:

```
var imgurl = "http://www.site-address.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/della-and-perry-300x300.jpg";
imgurl = imgurl.replace(/-[^.-]+(?=\.jpg)/, "-200x200")
console.log(imgurl);
// http://www.site-address.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/della-and-perry-200x200.jpg
```

Couldn't it be that you somehow execute the replacement twice?

[js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8XsyQ/)

Comment: That's very possible, I didn't think of that. It works for all of my other images, but for this della-and-perry, it returns della-and-200x200.jpg

Comment: Try adding some logging or do some debug to follow the control flow to check if you run it twice by mistake

Comment: Yea I'm thinking this may be it. The jsfiddle works as intended. Time for some digging

Comment: That must have been it. I had replaced the code, but I think it was cached. It seems to have updated and seems to be working %100. I've now tested multiple images. I've changed it over too `imgurl = imgurl.replace(/-[^.-]+(?=\.jpg|.gif|.png)/, "-200x200");`

Comment: It seems the issue was arising when the input image had no dimensions associated with it. `della-and-perry.jpg` turned into `della-and-200x200.jpg`

Shouldnt the regex only be replacing numbers?

Comment: Then you can use @Akinkunle's solution for matching dimension-like pattern only `/-\d+x\d+(?=\.jpg)/`. But from this on it's up to you what kind of patters do you want to match. You can even match only rectangle shaped images with this: `/-(\d+)x\1(?=\.jpg)/`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

`imgurl = imgurl.replace(/-[\d]{3}x[\d]{3}/, "-200x200")`

This would remove the `.jpg` extension:

`imgurl = imgurl.replace(/-[\d]{3}x[\d]{3}\.jpg/, "-200x200")`

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Do you want to remove the .jpg extension?

Comment: no I wanted to leave it, just testing it out now. Will accept in a minute. Thank you for your response!

Comment: It did work, but I wasn't aware my other regex expression was working as well. Depending on which option the user selects, some images may have no dimensions at all. I need to instruct the owner of the site the correct way to go about it to avoid the issue.